# Get intent result right after it finish in Titanium

Tags: android, android-intent, titanium

I have an app in Titanium Studio 3.1.3 that scan a QR code to process it. I do it this way: scan_qr.js

```
function scan_qr() {
    var Window = Ti.UI.createWindow({
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            navBarHidden   : false,
            exitOnClose    : false
        });

    function scan(callback){
        var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
            action: 'com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN'
        });

        intent.putExtra('SCAN_MODE', 'QR_SCAN_MODE');

        var activity = Ti.Android.currentActivity;
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, function(e) {
            if (e.resultCode == Ti.Android.RESULT_OK) {
                var contents = e.intent.getStringExtra('SCAN_RESULT'),
                    format   = e.intent.getStringExtra('SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT');

                qr_content = contents;
                callback(qr_content);

            } else if (e.resultCode == Ti.Android.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                qr_content = 'canceled';
            }
        });
    };

    return{
        scan: scan
    };
}

module.exports = scan_qr;
```

and the call function:

```
QR = require('scan_qr')
qr = new QR();
qr.scan(function(qr_code){alert(qr_code)});
```

But in never throws the alert(qr_code); it doesn't even set the qr_content
Maybe i'm not finishing the activity or the intent.

I tried to finish the activity by getting the window param from this code but it close the entire app. What can I do?

Comment: Finally I found the problem... the main activity was created as a "Heavyweight window" wich creates a new activity in android.
And this new window is created as a child activity, so UNTIL the main activity finish, the **startActivityForResult** callback is executed.

The solution is to create the main window as a "Lightweight window" and this window (the scan one) as an other Lightweight window, so it can finish after the intent and execute the callback function.

Check [link](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Activity) for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to put this code inside of your startActivityForResult function, maybe you are getting some errors that bring some light to your problem:

```
    if (e.error) {
        Ti.API.info('Error: '+e.error);
        Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
            title:'Error!',
            message:e.error
        }).show();    
    }
```

There is also a [titanium module to scan barcodes](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/barcode/mobile/android/dist), take a look at how to install modules on titanium [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Using_a_Module). An example using this module can be found [here](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/blob/master/barcode/mobile/android/example/app.js).